# please advise how to rewrite

Tags: c++, if-statement

I need an ascending output.
needs to be based only on if and else if statements. Is there anything I have missed or any shorter way to write the code?? please advise

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()  {
    int A, B, C;
    cin>>A>>B>>C;
    if ((A<=B)&&(B<=C)&&(A<=C)) {
        cout<<A<<" "<<B<<" "<<C;
    }else if((A<=B)&&(C<=B)&&(A<=B)) {
        cout<<A<<" "<<C<<" "<<B;
    }else if ((B<=A)&&(A<=C)&&(B<=C)) {
        cout<<B<<" "<<A<<" "<<C;
    }else if ((B<=C)&&(C<=A)&&(B<=A)) {
        cout<<B<<" "<<C<<" "<<A;
    }else if ((C<=A)&&(A<=B)&&(C<=B)) {
        cout<<C<<" "<<A<<" "<<B;
    }else if ((C<=B)&&(B<=A)&&(C<=A)) {
        cout<<C<<" "<<B<<" "<<A;
    }
   return 0;
}
```

expected ascending output

Comment: do you need `std::sort`?

Comment: If you want help improving working code you should post this on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  If you do decide to do so please delete the question here.  That said, you can get rid of the last condition in every one of your if statements.

Comment: You can get away with just 3 single-condition `if` blocks swapping items and a single `cout`  output. It is also possible to write this without any `if` blocks.

Comment: more, `<=` is a transitive relation for `int`s, so you don't need the third check for example there: `(A<=B)&&(B<=C)&&(A<=C)`

Comment: Just needed to look up on google for std::sort as I dont know what it is. just have started this C++ course and got to this problem where they give us three numbers A,B,C and only based on if/else and else if statements ask to have an ascending output

Comment: `std::sort` doesn't seem to satisfy requirements of only using condition operators.

Comment: You don't need ((A==B)&&(B==C)&&(A==C)), it's covered by the 6 other cases. Good work!  Now, write it for the case with variables A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J. :-)

Comment: Consider nesting your if statements.  You can then get away with a less compares when the CPU is running through your code.

Comment: @Jeffrey ik haha. completely forgot to delete that line. this is my 3rd day since I started this course so don't know much

Comment: Sometimes drawing pictures helps. Make a little flowchart and see where you are duplicating effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only `if`, there is alternative:

```
if (A <= B) {
    if (B <= C) {
        std::cout << A << " " << B << " " << C;
    } else if (A <= C) {
        std::cout << A << " " << C << " " << B;
    } else {
        std::cout << C << " " << A << " " << B;
    }
} else {
    if (A <= C) {
        std::cout << B << " " << A << " " << C;
    } else if (B <= C) {
        std::cout << B << " " << C << " " << A;
    } else {
        std::cout << C << " " << B << " " << A;
    }
}
```

Comment: that makes sense cause I have searched on google what std:: does but we haven't got there yet and I shouldn't be using it

Comment: This variant is horrible, it has 8 blocks instead of 7 in the OP's variant and about the same amount of `cout` output copypasta.

Comment: F-tonnes easier to read, though.

Comment: @VTT: less complexity (3 comparisons vs 21 (which could be just 10 if done properly)). As we cannot `sort` or `swap` values, we have to output each possible permutations, which is 6.

Comment: What makes you think swapping is prohibited? It is a trivial action even without standard library.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I have sorted it out :)